# Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'ListViewItem'

Tags: c#, listview, checkbox, eventhandler

I am trying to add a checked-box to a listview using C#. Something that seems to be straight forward has stopped me dead for the last few days. All is well until I want to add an event handler to the change of the check box.

```
    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
            this.components = new System.ComponentModel.Container();
            // more componets....
            // more componets.......
            // more componets.......

            this.listView1.SelectedIndexChanged += new System.EventHandler(this.listView1_SelectedIndexChanged);
            this.listView1.ItemChecked += new ItemCheckedEventArgs(this.listView1_ItemCheckChanged);
            // more componets....
    }

    private void listView1_ItemCheckChanged(object sender, System.Windows.Forms.ItemCheckedEventArgs e)
    {

        ListViewItem item = e.Item as ListViewItem;

        if (item != null)
        {
            if (item.Checked)
            {
                item.Checked = false;

            }
            else
            {
                item.Checked = true;

            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: ItemCheckedEventArgs? maybe you meant ItemCheckedEventHandler?

Answer (score 0):

Great thank

that was it changed it to

```
        this.listView1.ItemChecked += new ItemCheckedEventHandler(this.listView1_ItemCheckChanged);
```

Funny how that is not writen in any of the msdn. They just say remeber the event handler.